# how to create Opencart mysql query inside of AND condition

Tags: php, sql, opencart2.x

Actually, Opencart default model query is there i want add AND condition for inside of query (i want add email field ,the email is in order table) how will make the AND condition please help any one.
my query below:

```
 $order_query = $this->db->query(
        "SELECT *, (SELECT CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer c 
        WHERE c.customer_id = o.customer_id) AS customer, 
             (SELECT os.name 
                FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os 
                WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id 
                AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') 
        AS order_status 
        FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o 
        WHERE o.order_id = '" . (int)$order_id . "'");
```

Comment: how to make AND condition for this please help

Answer (score 0):

Just read:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Live example with joined table:

```
 $sql = "SELECT o.order_id, 
            CONCAT(o.firstname, ' ', o.lastname) AS customer, 
            (SELECT os.name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "order_status os WHERE os.order_status_id = o.order_status_id AND os.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') AS order_status, 
            o.invoice_prefix, 
            o.invoice_no, 
            o.shipping_code, 
            o.total,
            o.currency_code, 
            o.currency_value, 
            o.date_added, 
            o.date_modified,
            ot.value
            FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o
            LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_total` ot ON ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'total'";
```